# Sending a variable to a Django backend for processing

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am working on a payment processing script. The front end is a javascript module and the backend is a Django app. I seem to be missing something with my code and I can't pinpoint it. Here are the parts of the app:

```
{% extends 'dash.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block 'title' %} Subscription | Simpledocs {% endblock %}
{% block extra_title %}<h2>Subscription</h2>{% endblock %}
{% block paymentInfo %} {% endblock %}

{% block content %} 


<div class="columns is-centered">

    <div class="column is-5 box">
  
        {% if company.paid_till < today %}
        <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
       <div class="content">
      
        <h1 class="title is-4">
          <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          Account is not active
      </h1>
      Your company <strong>{{user_organization.organization}}</strong> is not active. Please renew the subscription.<br>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    
    <p class="label">We have great subcription options for you. Choose from our list either for monthly or annual plans</p><br>

    {% endif %}
    <h2>Subscription Packages</h2><br>
    <div class="select"> 
      <select
        name="search"
         onchange="updateButtonDataAmount(event)"
      >
        <option value="select-a-plan">Select A Plan</option>
        <option value="7.99">Starter - Monthly ($7.99/Month)</option>
        <option value="79.00">Starter - Annually ($79.00/Year)</option>
        <option value="49.00">Business - Monthly ($49.90/Month)</option>
        <option value="499.00">Business - Annually ($499.00/Year)</option>
      </select>
    </form>
    </div><br><br>

    <div id="searched-subs"></div><br><br>
    
  <button class="intaSendPayButton button is-btn-mycolor is-fullwidth" 
    data-amount="10" 
    data-currency="KES" 
    data-email="joe@doe.com" 
    data-first_name="JOE" 
    data-last_name="DOE" 
    data-country="KE">
    Pay Now
  </button><br>
    </div>
    </div>


  <script>


 new window.IntaSend({
    publicAPIKey: "publishing_key",
    live: false //set to true when going live
})
.on("COMPLETE", (results) => {
    // Send the results to the Django backend
    fetch("{% url 'paid' %}", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(results)
});
// redirect to a success page
window.location.href = "{% url 'paid' %}";
})
.on("FAILED", (results) => {
// Send the results to the Django backend
fetch("{% url 'paid' %}", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(results)
});
// redirect to a success page
window.location.href = "{% url 'paid' %}";
})
.on("IN-PROGRESS", (results) => console.log("Payment in progress status", results))
```

Here is the django backend. The payment process happens on "Subscription" page and should send the results to the "Paid" page for processing.

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages 
from ..decorators import renew_company
from ..forms import *
from ..models import *
from organizations.models import Organization, OrganizationUser, OrganizationOwner
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from datetime import datetime
from django.http import JsonResponse


@login_required(login_url='login')
def subscription(request):
    user = request.user
    user_organization = OrganizationUser.objects.get(user=user)
    company = Company.objects.filter(name = user_organization.organization.name).first()
    today = datetime.date.today()
    form = CompanyForm(request.POST)
    subscription = Subscription.objects.all()


   if user_organization.is_admin == True:

      if request.method == "POST":
          # Get the payment processing results from the request data
          results = request.GET.get("results")
          # Render the paid page, passing the results to the template
          return redirect ('paid')

        context = {'user_organization': user_organization, 'form': form, 
                'subscription': subscription, 'company': company, 'today': today}
        return render(request, 'registration/subscription.html', context)
   else:
        return HttpResponse('You are not authorised to view this page')


def paid(request):
    # Get the results variable from the request body
    results = request.POST.get("results")

    # return a response to the client
    return HttpResponse(results)
```

Simply put, how do I send the "Results" variable to be rendered on a django backend?

Comment: Can you explain what exactly is not working?

Comment: Hi Eugene, I have posted a better and clearer question on the same here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74729026/how-to-send-an-javascript-object-to-be-processed-on-a-django-backend 

You can let me know if this is better than this current post.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there's enough info to answer this question...

The template you gave only has `{% url 'paid' %}` so I don't know how the `subscription` method is called.  The `subscription` method has code that only runs on `POST` but then tries to retrieve data from `request.GET`.  It then tries to `redirect('paid')` but that won't cause a `POST` on `paid` with the data.  That just returns a 302 response with the URL of the `paid` view and no data.

I'm unfamiliar with the JavaScript code, but it looks like it's placing `results` directly into the body.  This means that the body won't say `results` in it, it will just contain the values from within the variable that was used to fill the body.  So, `request.POST.get('results')` will be empty.  You could try putting something like `print(request.POST)` and see what the contents look like to figure out how to access it.

Comment: Hi Tim, apologies. I have posted a better straightforward questions with better code examples. Please check it here and assist if you can: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74729026/how-to-send-an-javascript-object-to-be-processed-on-a-django-backend

Comment: @VinceMatinde Your new question is missing any details about how you are trying to "interact with the 'results'"...  In general, you should just edit your question instead of creating a new one.